# Game Engine Encryption for iTunes Connect Export Compliance?

Tags: ios, xcode, encryption, app-store-connect

I am using a Game Engine to create an iOS game app which allows me to drag-and-drop the generated files into Xcode to get the app binary. The said engine encrypts the files when exporting to an Xcode Project (to stop people reverse engineering their project files), then uploads the Xcode Project Build to the App Store using iTunes Connect.

How should I answer the following question during the submission process?:

> **Export Compliance**
>
> Is your app designed to use cryptography or does it contain or incorporate cryptography? (Select Yes even if your app is only utilizing the encryption available in iOS or OS X.)

More info on the compliance can be found [here](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Managing%20Your%20Apps_Export%20Compliance).

Comment: `If you use a Drag-and-Drop Game Engine to make a game, that encrypts their files when exporting from their Software to an Xcode Project ` Can you elaborate on this statement?

Comment: Thanks for posting @NimeshNeema Well, there's some Game Making Software that upon exporting from their Software to Xcode (after the game has been made in their Software), encrypt their files. Then you open up the Xcode project in Xcode and upload to the App Store. So I'm wondering if this step of encryption affects the Export Compliance of iTunesConnect. Thank you.

Comment: You’ll need to select no. The clause is applicable if you are encrypting user data in some way or the other (ie using 3rd party or iOS SDK built in framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely select **no** in this case.

The said clause is applicable if you are encrypting user/app generated data either using iOS SDK provided or any other 3rd party APIs.

What you are getting from the Game engine is getting added as an *asset* to the Xcode project, which will ultimately generate the iOS app, the clause doesn't apply in your case.

Additionally, take a look at this help document from Apple:

- [Export compliance documentation for encryption](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devc3f64248f).

It should further help in answering your query.